# How to config sveltekit SSR for Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-functions, svelte, sveltekit, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I recently started a project using Svelte + Firebase. I am now trying to switch from SPA to SSR. From the [firebase-framework-tools](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools) repo I found that support is still experimental, but it should work. I followed the instruction on their repo,changed the svelte adapter from `adapter-static` to `adapter-auto` and my `svelte.config.js` is this:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto'
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: [vitePreprocess()],

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        alias: {
            $stores: './src/stores',
            $components: './src/lib/components',
        },
    },
}

export default config
```

This is my `firebase.json` file:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-east1"
    }
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5055
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

Yet after depployment I get this error:
[image]

If anyone has deployed a ssr svelte project in firebase in the past can you tell me what am I missing? Can you please guide me in the right way?